# Windows: Writing & to a file from command line

Tags: batch-file

I'm attempting to create a batch file which creates a vbs file which will accept arguments to create a new internet favorite, and then have the batch file call that vbs script and pass it arguments in order to create the proper shortcuts. Perhaps I'm overcomplicating things. What I have so far is this:

```
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>Favorites.vbs
echo set oShellLink=WshShell.CreateShortcut(Wscript.Arguments.Named("s")&".url") >>Favorites.vbs
echo oShellLink.TargetPath = Wscript.Arguments.Named("target") >>Favorites.vbs
echo oShellLink.Save >>Favorites.vbs

cscript Favorites.vbs /target:"<website>" /s:"<what I want it named>"

del Favorites.vbs
```

The problem comes in at the & since it is interpreting it as starting a new command rather than as continuing the text to be sent to the file. Since I'm trying to create a `.url` file, it has to use that as the file extension, but I'm floundering today on how to get it to work. So, how do I make a command line send `&` to a file as part of the text? Unless someone has a more streamlined option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `^` when echoing poison characters - such as `echo ^&`

Comment: I feel really dumb now. Thank you, that works perfectly!